# Severity: Warning Message: Trying to access array offset on value of type null Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, runtime-error, codeigniter-3

I have a serious problem with the Controller section of codeigniter, can anyone help me how to fix this?
Here my Code:

```
private function _validasi()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('tanggal_keluar', 'Tanggal Keluar', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('barang_id', 'Barang', 'required');

    $input = $this->input->post('barang_id', true);
    $stok = $this->admin->get('barang',['id_barang' => $input])['stok']; //Line Number: 28
    $stok_valid = $stok + 1;

    $this->form_validation->set_rules(
        'jumlah_keluar',
        'Jumlah Keluar',
        "required|trim|numeric|greater_than[0]|less_than[{$stok_valid}]",
        [
            'less_than' => "Jumlah Keluar tidak boleh lebih dari {$stok}"
        ]
    );
}
```

and this is the error
[image]

Comment: Please always add all error messages as text as well. Then SO can index those as well, allowing others with the same/similar errors to find this question.

Comment: `$this->admin->get('barang',['id_barang' => $input])` doesn't seem to return an array, it returns `null` so when you're trying to read it as an array (by adding `['stok']` after it), you'll get that message. If a method/function can return different types of values, always check the response before trying to use it.